# Can't find OpenEdx path in IBM Cloud using Shell

Tags: ibm-cloud, openedx

recently I installed OpenEdx on my IBM cloud and my OpenEdx website is live and running on public URL, but the problem is I can't find any path or directory in my IBMcloud / I am using IBM-Cloud - Cli version to find.

Can you please help me to find OpenEdx directory in IBM Cloud?

Thanks

Comment: Hi blindcoder, welcome to SO :) Please familiarise yourself with [asking questions](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) before writing your next one!

Comment: Are you following the instructions on this page? https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/cloud/library/cl-openedx-softlayer-app/index.html

Thanks